# SVG drop-shadow makes PNG image disappear in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg

I'm adding a cross-browser compatible drop-shadow to a png image (with transparency). It works in Chrome and Safari, but in Firefox the PNG image simply doesn't display at all.

Here's my webpage with the trout in hand logo PNG image in the header:
http://parkerrichard.com/wordpress/

I'm using CSS and SVG to display the drop-shadow as follows:

```
.shadowed {
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(20px 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
filter: url(#drop-shadow);
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=12, OffY=12, Color='#444')";
filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=12, OffY=12, Color='#444')";
}
```

UPDATE: SVG + image with class of .shadowed (copied into my html):

```
<img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive shadowed center-image animated fadeIn">

<svg height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<filter id="drop-shadow">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="4"/>
    <feOffset dx="20" dy="20" result="offsetblur"/>
    <feFlood flood-color="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"/>
    <feComposite in2="offsetblur" operator="in"/>
    <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </feMerge>
</filter>
</svg>
```

Please let me know if you have any ideas on how to make this PNG appear with a drop-shadow in Firefox! Thank you for your time.

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot to include that bit in my HTML example. I've since added it

Comment: That's not what I was talking about: filter: url(#drop-shadow); means filter: url(the file I'm written in#drop-shadow) so if that's not the html file it won't work.

Comment: So before #drop-shadow do I add an html path name to the file containing the SVG? I don't quite follow you, my apologies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`filter: url(#drop-shadow);`

The Firefox problem is that : `Can not find it`.
Move `svg` tag to the top of body, maybe your problem was solved.
This link may also be useful
[Creating a True Cross-Browser Drop Shadow Effect With CSS3 & SVG](http://thenewcode.com/600/Creating-a-True-Cross-Browser-Drop-Shadow-Effect-With-CSS-amp-SVG)

Comment: Thanks @Hamix, I see where the problem lies. I created a new file, "shadow.svg", added the svg code, and tried to link the filter to that file. My site is based in WordPress and I having difficulty finding the proper path name. I'm now trying this to no avail:  filter: url(wp-content/themes/troutinhand/shadow.svg#drop-shadow);

Comment: Got it! Changed the filter path to "../../shadow.svg" and that did it. Thanks for your help @Hamix!

Answer (score 1):

Firefox accepts the filter now.

So you can use something like:

```
.shadowed {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=4, OffY=6, Color='#444')";
  filter: drop-shadow(4px 6px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.77));
}
```

Comment: That's great to hear, thanks for the heads up comrade